# Opening ZIP file from email giving bad URI path

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am trying to figure out why, when I try to open an email attachment that I have an intent filter for, it is giving me a URI that I can't read from. The URI it is giving me is:

```
content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/32/RAW
```

instead of:

```
/sdcard/Download/Attachments/MYZIP.ZIP
```

The code I am calling to get the path is `this.getIntent().getData().getPath();`

The only way that it opens correctly is by downloading it first so it has a path that I am able to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a custom URI provided by third party app. You should check their APIs about the permissions to work with their content URIs. Here is [some information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Intents).

Normally you can use [`ContentResolver.openInputStream(android.net.Uri)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29) to get the `InputStream` from that URI, something like:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

// ...

public static void test(Context context) throws Exception {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/32/RAW");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
            context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        zis.close();
    }
}
```

But that depends on the vendor (if they provide such access or not). So make sure to check their SDK/ APIs…

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? Seems crazy to me that opening a file attachment from mail requires vendor-specific API access.